# what is the derivative of $e^{x^x}$ can't find it anywhere

Tags: calculus

i have trouble finding the derivative of $e^{x^x}$
the answer is supposed to be   $$(\ln(x)+1)(x^x)(e^{x^x}))$$
but i don't know how i have tried everything
$e^{x^x}$  i can't make the program recognize it correctly

Comment: chain rule + $x^x=e^{x\ln x}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You're likely to get more helpful answers (as well as getting positive votes rather than negative ones) if you explain *what* you tried, rather than just saying that you tried a lot of things.

Answer (score 3):

Directly applying the chain rule
in the form
$(e^{f(x)})' = f'(x) e^{f(x)}$,
and using
$x^x = e^{x \ln x}$,

$\begin{align}
(e^{x^x})'
&=(x^x)'e^{x^x}\\
&=(e^{x \ln x})'e^{x^x}\\
&=(x \ln x)'e^{x \ln x}e^{x^x}\\
&=(1+ \ln x)x^{x}e^{x^x}\\
\end{align}
$

Comment: why is $ (x \ln x)' $  equal to $ (e^{x \ln x})' $

Answer (score 1):

Using the chain rule, it suffices to find the derivative of $y = x^x$; to do this, we use logarithmic differentiation:

$$\ln y = x \ln x \implies \frac{y'}{y} = x \cdot \frac{1}{x} + 1 \ln{x} = 1 + \ln{x}$$

Hence,

$$y' = y (1 + \ln{x}) = x^x (1 + \ln{x})$$

Now to find the original, simply apply the chain rule.

Comment: @Hellion whenever you encountered $f(x)^{g(x)}$ type expression use above method